# Index Check in OpenEdge 10.2b which uses Oracle schema

Tags: oracle, progress-4gl, openedge

How to know index usage of particular module in Openedge 10.2 which uses Oracle db schema?

I have used XREF but .xrf does not give any index details for my module, so I have run below simple query and then checked in .xrf but no index detail available.

```
FOR EACH tablename NO-LOCK USE-INDEX indexname:
DISPLAY tablename.field.
END.
```

Please help me how to get index detail for Progress db using oracle schema.

Comment: Hello to Stack Overflow! As you may have seen, I've edited your question to be more compliant with SO rules, please read FAQs or ask moderators if you have any doubts!

Comment: Could you include your compile statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I assume you are using Oracle DataServer from Progress.

If that is the case, bear in mind that all USE-INDEX will be translated basically into ORDER BY in the resulting query, so mostly being used to order not to access the data.

If you want a know how your information is accessed you'll need to enable [qt_debug](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/oe102bhtml/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=dmora/01dmoratitle.html) when connecting to the schema holder, that will allow you to print many information about how your progress code is translated to SQL to access the Oracle DB. You'll need to analyze those SQL (SQL EXPLAIN as an example) to see the performance of your queries and how they are accessing the DB.